# Get AWS bucket List Boto/Boto3

Tags: amazon-s3, boto, boto3, tbucketlist

I have developed a Tornado API which gets me the AWS S3 bucket contents, Below is the code snippet which run perfectly with Boto. However this doesn't work for the buckets in some different location.

The method returns a list(resp) which is consists filename, size, and file type.

**Want to achieve similar using Boto3. Tried a lot but Boto3 methods returns the all contents of the s3 bucket with full path.**

```
def post(self):
    try:
        resp = []
        path = self.get_argument('path')
        bucket_name = self.get_argument('bucket_name')
        path_len = len(path)
        conn = S3Connection()
        bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        folders = bucket.list(path, "/")
        for folder in folders:
            if folder.name == path:
                continue
            if str(folder.name).endswith("/"):
                file_type = 'd'
                file_name = str(folder.name)[path_len:-1]
            else:
                _file_size = self.filesize(folder.size)
                file_type = 'f'
                file_name = str(folder.name)[path_len:]
            resp.append({"bucket": bucket_name, "path": path, "name": file_name, "type": file_type,
                         "size": _file_size if file_type == 'f' else ""})
        self.write(json.dumps(resp))
```

Answer (score 0):

Razvan Tudorica built a small replacement for Boto3's upload and delete methods which uses Tornado’s AsyncHTTPClient; he published a blog post [here](http://razvantudorica.net/08/upload-asynchronously-to-amazon-s3-using-tornado/) concerning the work and posted his code on [GitHub](https://github.com/raztud/tornados3).

As the original SO enquiry highlights that the code snippet supplied "doesn't work for the buckets in some different location", of specific interest here is Razvan's note that, "the main idea around [his] replacement is to use botocore to build the request (AWS wants the requests to be signed using different algorithms based on AWS zones and request data) and only to use the AsyncHTTPClient for the actual asynchronous call."

I hope Razvan's work still proves useful to you or, minimally, to others researching similar efforts (as I was recently).